# CakePHP error 'page not found' error - how to avoid

Tags: cakephp

I need some background information about CakePHP, and how it works...

let's say that i have method (function) defined in CakePHP's controller, ie. deleteItem, like

```
function deleteItem( $id = null ) 
{
    $this->PublicationNumeration->delete( $id, true );
}
```

The CMS I developed works ok, proper record is deleted ($id), and it works fine.

But if I try to call this method from browser, I am getting the error 'page not found'.

Is it possible to skip that error (no matter how)?

Comment: Maybe that's a rubbish anwser but shouldn't you have to call a `render()` or `redirect()` function once it's deleted ?

Comment: What are you expecting it to do? Go to a page that says the item has been deleted? Why is no data being passed from controller to view? Normally, I would expect an action like this to set a message (e.g. "Item deleted successfully"), and then redirect to another action.

Answer (score 3):

For development mode, set debug value to 2 in app/config/core.php:

```
Configure::write('debug', 2);
```

If you set debug value to 2, you can get detailed message of what happening. From your description, there are two possibilities:

1. record with given id has been deleted, or
2. view from current action is not exist. Usually in delete action, you
   don't create view but redirect it to
   somewhere else (which you not do in
   code above).

Comment: nope. as i said, page exists. method exists. it works if i call it from caphp application, it works. but if i call it directly from browser, i get error "page not found".

Comment: please set debug value to 2 and post here the error message so we can get detailed information on what happens.

Answer (score 1):

If you want, you can create your own custom error pages in `/views/errors`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're including the controller's name in the URL as well. If your controller's class name is CategoriesController and you want to delete an item with an ID of 4, for example, make sure you're going to this address in the browser:

```
http://www.example.com/categories/deleteItem/4
```

Answer (score 0):

The page is not found because you haven't created it (deleteItem.ctp). After the delete statement, put a redirect to the page you want to return to, usually an index page after a delete operation.